# How to eliminate "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform " warning?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

The warning is

Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to Collection<? extends String>

Do I need a type cast somewhere?

```
public class ETLStepType {
    public static final ArrayList<String> ETLStepTypes = ( 
            new ArrayList<String> ((Arrays.asList(new String[] {"constant", 
                                                          "append", 
                                                          "insertupdate", 
                                                          "tableinput",
                                                          "filterrows",
                                                          "dblookup",
                                                          "selectvalues"}))));

}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` should return a `List<String>` if `T` is properly inferred to `String`. Try using varargs instead - there's no reason to create a new array

Comment: I don't think that code produces that warning. At least not with any recent version of the normal Java compiler.

Comment: @khelwood https://imgur.com/a/k6Dtl9O

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://repl.it/repls/CarelessLightblueTriggers

Comment: Well, the only warning *my* IDE emits, is that the constant name `ETLStepTypes` does not follow the naming conventions. You should follow these Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase, class names in PascalCase, and constants in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. `ETLStepTypes` should be ~ETL_STEP_TYPES`.

Comment: @nicomp Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: @MCEmperor yes I am

Comment: @MCEmperor I get the warning.

Comment: Well, I've seen more than once that the behavior of Eclipse's internal compiler is different to other compilers in some corner cases. From what I've seen, most of the differences involved generics, type inference and varargs.

Comment: Maybe Eclipse has a setting for "don't warn me about imaginary problems"

Comment: in Intellij Idea getting "Redundant array creation for calling varargs method" warning, which fixed by removing 'new String []{ and }' so try ... ETLStepTypes = (
                new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList("constant",
                        "append",
                        "insertupdate", ... to fix the issue

Comment: @greencrest Yes! Post your solution as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Intellij Idea getting "Redundant array creation for calling varargs method" warning, which fixed by removing 'new String []{ and }' so try

```
        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("constant",
                "append",
                "insertupdate",
                "tableinput",
                "filterrows",
                "dblookup",
                "selectvalues"))
```

to fix the issue